# EBNF or BNF of LINQ? Associativity of join? Other clauses?

Tags: linq

I am in search of BNF or EBNF of LINQ. It seems as if a grammar specification of C# is not readily available anywhere, but then, the LINQ fragment might be easy to infer, if not found.

In particular, I cannot figure out the precedence/associativity of join. Note that join may include nested queries, for example:

```
var result = from a in T 
             join b in B on a.key equals b.key
             join c in C on ??? 
             where ... 
             ...
```

Here is the grammar I came up with so far:

```
<Query> ::= <From> <Body>
<Body> ::= <Clause>* <Conclusion> <Continutation>?
<Clause> ::= <From> | <Join> | <Let> | <Order> | <OrderBy>
<From> ::= "from " <Item> "in " <Source> 
<Join> ::= "join " <Item> "in " <Source> "on " <Key> "equals " <Key> ( "into " <Item> )?
<Let> ::= "let " <Item> " = " <Selection> 
<Order> ::= "where " <Condition> 
<OrderBy> ::= "orderby " ( <Key> ( "ascending " | "descending " )?)+
<Conclusion> ::=  <Select> | <Group> 
<Select> ::= " select " <Selection> 
<Group> ::= " group " <Selection> "by " <Key> 
<Continutation> ::= "into " <Item> <Body> 
<Item> ::= "x" [0-9]+ " "
<Source> ::= "DB" [0-9]+  <Id> " "
<Selection> ::= "new " "{ " <Fields> "} "
<Key> ::= "K" [0-9]+  <Id> " "
<Condition> ::= <And>
<And> ::= <Or> ( " && " <Or> )
<Or>  ::= <Not> ( " || " <Not> )
<Not> ::= " !"? ( "(" <Condition> ")" | <Comparison> )  
<Comparison> ::= <Value> ( "<" | ">" | "==" | "<=" | ">=" | "!=" ) <Value>
<Value> ::= <Key> | <Number>
<Number> ::= [0-0] | ( [1-9] [0-9]*  )
<Fields> ::= <Field> (", " <Field>)*
<Field> ::= "F" <Item>
<Id> ::= ( [a-z] | [A-Z] ) ( E | ( [0-9] | [A-Z] | [a-z] ) )
```

You can play with this grammar in here: https://bnfplayground.pauliankline.com/?bnf=%3CQuery%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CFrom%3E%20%3CBody%3E%0A%3CBody%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CClause%3E*%20%3CConclusion%3E%20%3CContinutation%3E%3F%0A%3CClause%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CFrom%3E%20%7C%20%3CJoin%3E%20%7C%20%3CLet%3E%20%7C%20%3COrder%3E%20%7C%20%3COrderBy%3E%0A%3CFrom%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22from%20%22%20%3CItem%3E%20%22in%20%22%20%3CSource%3E%20%0A%3CJoin%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22join%20%22%20%3CItem%3E%20%22in%20%22%20%3CSource%3E%20%22on%20%22%20%3CKey%3E%20%22equals%20%22%20%3CKey%3E%20(%20%22into%20%22%20%3CItem%3E%20)%3F%0A%3CLet%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22let%20%22%20%3CItem%3E%20%22%20%3D%20%22%20%3CSelection%3E%20%0A%3COrder%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22where%20%22%20%3CCondition%3E%20%0A%3COrderBy%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22orderby%20%22%20(%20%3CKey%3E%20(%20%22ascending%20%22%20%7C%20%22descending%20%22%20)%3F)%2B%0A%3CConclusion%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%20%3CSelect%3E%20%7C%20%3CGroup%3E%20%0A%3CSelect%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22%20select%20%22%20%3CSelection%3E%20%0A%3CGroup%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22%20group%20%22%20%3CSelection%3E%20%22by%20%22%20%3CKey%3E%20%0A%3CContinutation%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22into%20%22%20%3CItem%3E%20%3CBody%3E%20%0A%3CItem%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22x%22%20%5B0-9%5D%2B%20%22%20%22%0A%3CSource%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22DB%22%20%5B0-9%5D%2B%20%20%3CId%3E%20%22%20%22%0A%3CSelection%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22new%20%22%20%22%7B%20%22%20%3CFields%3E%20%22%7D%20%22%0A%3CKey%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22K%22%20%5B0-9%5D%2B%20%20%3CId%3E%20%22%20%22%0A%3CCondition%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CAnd%3E%0A%3CAnd%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3COr%3E%20(%20%22%20%26%26%20%22%20%3COr%3E%20)%0A%3COr%3E%20%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CNot%3E%20(%20%22%20%7C%7C%20%22%20%3CNot%3E%20)%0A%3CNot%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22%20!%22%3F%20(%20%22(%22%20%3CCondition%3E%20%22)%22%20%7C%20%3CComparison%3E%20)%20%20%0A%3CComparison%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CValue%3E%20(%20%22%3C%22%20%7C%20%22%3E%22%20%7C%20%22%3D%3D%22%20%7C%20%22%3C%3D%22%20%7C%20%22%3E%3D%22%20%7C%20%22!%3D%22%20)%20%3CValue%3E%0A%3CValue%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CKey%3E%20%7C%20%3CNumber%3E%0A%3CNumber%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%5B0-0%5D%20%7C%20(%20%5B1-9%5D%20%5B0-9%5D*%20%20)%0A%3CFields%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3CField%3E%20(%22%2C%20%22%20%3CField%3E)*%0A%3CField%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22F%22%20%3CItem%3E%0A%3CId%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20(%20%5Ba-z%5D%20%7C%20%5BA-Z%5D%20)%20(%20E%20%7C%20(%20%5B0-9%5D%20%7C%20%5BA-Z%5D%20%7C%20%5Ba-z%5D%20)%20)%20&name=Real%20Numbers

For example, you can generate sample queries based on this syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by "precedence of join"?

Comment: And also "the LINQ fragment might be easy to infer, if not found"?

Comment: Perhaps you need to post some examples of the code you're looking at and what you specifically want to know about that code?

Comment: LINQ operators don't have precedence; they are just ordinary C# extension methods, so chaining multiple LINQ operators together is exactly the same as chaining any other C# methods together.   i.e.  the order they are called is simply the order in which you see them chained together in the code.

Comment: @BenCottrell Perhaps the OP is asking about query syntax instead of fluent/lambda syntax.

Comment: Try starting [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/570a63a6e0a4e98b9f5ad0af1b3653535937e030/csharp/CSharpParser.g4#L348). There are other versions of the C# grammar for other parser generators. I can't say whether the Antlr grammar implements operator precedence correctly in query expressions, but I think it is derived from a spec at one point.

Comment: @NetMage There is no difference; my comment applies to both.    Query syntax and Method syntax both use extension methods and both behave in exactly the same way (i.e. chained extension method calls).  The documentation describes them as 'semantically identical' - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: @BenCottrell - The OP is seemingly after the syntactical precedence, not semantic.

Comment: @Enigmativity The relevant part of the specification is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#query-expressions -- Unless I am misunderstanding, no such concept as precedence exists for Query syntax.   It mentions *"translation from query expressions to method invocations is a syntactic mapping"* and also states *"The translations are listed in order of application"*.   Am I missing something else?

Comment: @BenCottrell The _translations_ are applied in that order, which means e.g. `select`..`into` and `group`..`by`..`into` get transformed before other forms. As it turns out, the end result does not re-order the clauses (much), though some are subsumed into one method call. And of course parentheses change the order of operation.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I edited the question to clarify the precedence issue, also added what I could infer. The EBNF I provide can generate examples.

Comment: @BenCottrell: there is a difference between the query and method invocations: In the latter, precedence is determined by parenthesis. Think of the famous dangling else problem. It disappears if we use method calls

Comment: @BenCottrell - The BNF specifies the language and it shows how we syntactically group code - hence precedence.

Comment: I see, thank you, that was confusion on my part (for some reason I'd fixated on the operators themselves rather than the lexical tokens).   OP - I'm unsure whether you'd managed to find a copy of ECMA-334 before now; it turns out that a draft of the document is available to download for free at https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/ (Section 12.17, page 202) may contain (some) answers.   The C# design team also seem to maintain an unofficial version on github: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/spec/expressions.md#query-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#query-expressions) specifies the query syntax:

```
query_expression
    : from_clause query_body
    ;

from_clause
    : 'from' type? identifier 'in' expression
    ;

query_body
    : query_body_clauses? select_or_group_clause query_continuation?
    ;

query_body_clauses
    : query_body_clause
    | query_body_clauses query_body_clause
    ;

query_body_clause
    : from_clause
    | let_clause
    | where_clause
    | join_clause
    | join_into_clause
    | orderby_clause
    ;

let_clause
    : 'let' identifier '=' expression
    ;

where_clause
    : 'where' boolean_expression
    ;

join_clause
    : 'join' type? identifier 'in' expression 'on' expression 'equals' expression
    ;

join_into_clause
    : 'join' type? identifier 'in' expression 'on' expression 'equals' expression 'into' identifier
    ;

orderby_clause
    : 'orderby' orderings
    ;

orderings
    : ordering (',' ordering)*
    ;

ordering
    : expression ordering_direction?
    ;

ordering_direction
    : 'ascending'
    | 'descending'
    ;

select_or_group_clause
    : select_clause
    | group_clause
    ;

select_clause
    : 'select' expression
    ;

group_clause
    : 'group' expression 'by' expression
    ;

query_continuation
    : 'into' identifier query_body
    ;
```

Comment: I marked it as correct, even though I am not sure it is. Perhaps I am missing something? in the full bnf you quote, there is a production- expression->non-assignment->query? So where is the associativity and precedence defined?